# How are the back ends of apps created? Also how is the front end designed? Is it done like a wap site and them linked to Xcode?

Tags: ios, web-applications

I tried to find the answer to this question but could not, to be more precise, some apps like instagram have a custom backend, like they have a profile tab in the app where the users profile is stored, including the pics they upload.I want to know how is that page created, and how is the data saved to that page.So in short,if for my app I want to have a profile tab,how do I go about creating it, and how is the data storage done? I wanted to know whether the profile page under my profile tab is created, as in is it done in Xcode or some web design application and linked to Xcode?
Don't get me wrong, I'm not asking for the detailed process,just what software is used and a basic outline.

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a Tabbed Application? As far as the "back end", most apps will have some sort of back end service that runs, usually in a RestFUL manner. I would do a google search for RestFUL Web Services.

Comment: Please check the [URL](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)

Comment: No, I know how to create a tabbed application, actually as you said I wanted to know whether the profile page under my profile tab is created, as in is it done in Xcode or some web design application and linked to Xcode.Thanks I will search for RestFUL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back ends are PHP or any other server side languages, these are presented as service APIs interface, the most common is RESTful interfaces, the application connects to these RESTful services to store and retrieve data from

Comment: @OccamsRazor i would suggest PHP since its the easies in my opinion :) also dont forget to accept the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Omar Abdelhafith So u mean, the profile page in instagram for instance  is designed using PHP as normal wap site and linked in Xcode?

Comment: It could be done as normal HTML page , or it could be sending JSON data and leave the creation on the profile to the iPhone application

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to read up on core data as any offline profile data is probably stored in core data or as NSUser Defaults.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, will read up, but I was more interested to know whether,for example the profile page in instagram where you see all the pics u uploaded etc, is done.Is it designed like a normal wap site and linked in Xcode?

Comment: The instagram app certainly does use a UIWebView to display the contents of a web page and as Omar stated it probably is developed using PHP